# ATTINY85 variants

Tags: arduino, attiny, attiny85

I am using an Arduino as ISP to program Attiny chips at 8Mhz (internal). I am using the Arduino IDE as I find this easier. Some of the chips I was programming however appeared to be working at 1Mhz instead of 8Mhz. After pulling my hair out for 30 minutes thinking it was random, I realised that they have different numbers on them (Both Attiny85-20PU) but one had 1512 (works properly) and one has 1822 (does not work properly). They are both from ATMEL.

What is this number, and also how can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the date code. "1822" is a misread since that date is in the future. You can get around this by unprogramming the CKDIV8 fuse which comes programmed from the factory.

Comment: IS this doable through the Arduino IDE? I assumed by specifying the 8Mhz clock through the GUI the IDE would take care of the fuses.

Comment: Only if the `boards.txt` for it has the fuses specified properly and you choose to burn the "bootloader" (which is actually just a blank or blink sketch).